# Complex ftdetect plugin

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I want to create vim syntax highlighting file for custom programming language. Namely C/AL which is internal for Dynamics NAV system.

The issue is that it's impossible to detect via file extension. Historically C/AL uses *.TXT files. It also not good to highlight all *.TXT files, since some of them might contain C/AL code.

I know that VIM is able to detect language not only by extension, but also by file content. And I have found some examples in [official manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html). However it states I can use either first approach, or second.

Is it possible to combine them in one go? Where I can find an examples of such behavior?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about why/how you want to use both approaches? either you detect by file name with autocmds or with a script that can use a more complicated procedure to determine the filetype.

Comment: Any chance you've shared that C/AL syntax file somewhere? I hate the editor in Dynamics NAV. 2013 R2 still doesn't even have a real undo. And VIM = magic :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use getline to refine your detection based on file contents.  For example, this detects XML in .tmp files:

```
autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.tmp
    \ if getline(1) =~ '<?\s*xml.*?>' |
    \     setfiletype xml |
    \ endif
```

Another approach is to add a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline) to each C/AL file.